# .Net Core Startup Constructor

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm new to .NET Core and have been reading turotials on several diffrent sites. One thing I've come across that's confusing me is that I've seen two different tutorials with two different constructors for the TSartup class. When I create a.Net Core project in Visual Studio, I see this in the constructor:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

    }
```

However, in the artitcle I read, Startup Constructor is as follows:

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

    }
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two I apologize if this seems a bit trivial but I literally just started learning .net core and I want a thorough understanding of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is the newer of them and is the recommended one for asp.net core 2.0. In 1.x the first one was used in the project templates and configuration was created in the Startup constructor. Now configuration is created in Program.cs and injected into Startup constructor in the 2.0 project templates.
Both approaches should still work but the one that takes IConfiguration as a parameter is what I would use.